# How to write media statistics for all types of video containers using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata

I need to write video and audio statistical data like the average bit-rate, frequency of the audio, etc. **in-place to the video file** while retaining the other metadata like title, comments, etc.

Main point here is that it should perform the function of 'mkvpropedit --add-statistics-tags'. 'ffprobe' is useless for my need. 'ffprobe' does not make changes to the file itself, at best is can generate another file containing the metadata.

If there is no such solution possible using the ffmpeg tools please say so.

Note: Moderators please read the question details carefully before marking it as duplicate. I require a universal solution applicable to all video formats (hence ffmpeg).

Comment: There is no universal user metadata format so no universal solution.

Comment: Ok, I kind of expected. So is there any specific solution for mp4 and for avi?